# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error ONLY in iPad, NOT in iPhone & Simulator

Tags: ios, ios6

I am suffering through EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in my iOS app. Everything works fine on simulator & iPhone 4S device BUT I get this error on iPad2 device. I have iOS 6.0 installed on both iPhone & iPad2 devices.

Here is the functionality: I have a Christmas Tree (UIImageView) on background image (UIImageView). I have lots of ornaments (UIImageViews) on top of Christmas tree and they all fall down when user shakes device. Now we can drag the ornaments from floor and can decorate them on the Tree. I noticed that it crashes ONLY when I leave/release the ornament when its touching the Tree partially (I mean when the ornament is touching edges of the tree and is still on the background UIImageView and I release/drop the ornament)

Error comes at `CGFloat red   = (rawData[byteIndex]     * 1.0) / 255.0;` of code inside `-(NSArray*)getRGBAsFromImage:(UIImage*)image atX:(int)xx andY:(int)yy count:(int)count` method. Below is the code...

I tried various methods to resolve it but no use. Would greatly appreciate if someone can guide me in correct direction.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //[Audio1 pause];
    NSLog(@"touchesEnded:withEvent:");
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (pageNum == 9) //ROCKEFELLER CHRISTMAS TREE
    {
        NSLog(@"touchesEnded:withEvent: if (pageNum == 9)");
        float trans_y,drop_second;
        UIImageView *temp_view;
        //        UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
        CGPoint _location=currentPosition;

        //for (int i=601; i<636; i++) {
        for (int i=921; i<956; i++) {
            if ([touch view] ==[self.view viewWithTag:i]) {
                press_ornament=YES;
                //invalidate the transform scale.
                temp_view=(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
                temp_view.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;

                //detect the position are inside tree, or outside
                color_array= [self getRGBAsFromImage:tree.image atX:_location.x andY:_location.y count:1];
                color = color_array[0];

                //Call getRed:green:blue:alpha: and pass in pointers to floats to take the answer.
                [color getRed: &red_color green: &green_color blue: &blue_color alpha: &alpha_value];

                NSLog(@"red = %f. Green = %f. Blue = %f. Alpha = %f",red_color,green_color,blue_color,alpha_value);

                // Using alpha, decide inside the tree inside the tree view domain
                if ((alpha_value == 1) && (tree.frame.origin.x < _location.x) &&(_location.x <tree.frame.origin.x +tree.frame.size.width) && (tree.frame.origin.y < _location.y) && (_location.y< tree.frame.origin.y + tree.frame.size.height)) {

                    [touch view].center=CGPointMake(_location.x, _location.y);

                }
                //outside the tree fall the ornament
                else{
                    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
                        trans_y=280-[touch view].frame.origin.y;
                        drop_second =trans_y/150;
                        temp_view=(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];

                        // Move the image
                        [self moveImage:temp_view duration:drop_second curve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear x:temp_view.frame.origin.x y:280];
                    }
                    else{
                        trans_y=730-[touch view].frame.origin.y;
                        drop_second =trans_y/300;
                        temp_view=(UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];

                        // Move the image
                        [self moveImage:temp_view duration:drop_second curve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear x:temp_view.frame.origin.x y:730];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    }



//This is the function that get point color.
-(NSArray*)getRGBAsFromImage:(UIImage*)image atX:(int)xx andY:(int)yy count:(int)count
{
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];

    // First get the image into your data buffer
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    //    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    //    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    NSInteger width=tree.frame.size.width;
    NSInteger height=tree.frame.size.height;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    // Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
    int byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * yy) + xx * bytesPerPixel;
    for (int ii = 0 ; ii < count ; ++ii)
    {
        CGFloat red   = (rawData[byteIndex]     * 1.0) / 255.0;
        CGFloat green = (rawData[byteIndex + 1] * 1.0) / 255.0;
        CGFloat blue  = (rawData[byteIndex + 2] * 1.0) / 255.0;
        CGFloat alpha = (rawData[byteIndex + 3] * 1.0) / 255.0;
        byteIndex += 4;

        UIColor *acolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
        [result addObject:acolor];
    }

    free(rawData);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect you do not get the `xx,yy` that you expect and therefore you come outside your allocated block. Try to NSLog or debug the `xx,yy` and see what `byteindex` you end up with.

or put in an assert to catch if you come outside range.

```
NSAssert( bytesPerRow * width  * yy + xx * bytesPerPixel 
  < height * width * 4, 
  @"outside range!" );
```

I would also suggest that you make your function shorter and move the tmp variables to the block where they are used. It makes the code a bit easier to read.